# Angular SVG URL from scope does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, safari, compatibility

(Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/S0nSaeFU2TjSSDgvTL3s?p=preview)

I'm trying to dynamically set the URL of an SVG in my Angular app.

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.svg = "http://url/of/svg.svg"
```

And in my HTML I have:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="{{svg}}" />
```

On Chrome and Firefox when I load my page I first get a 404 for `{scope}`, I then get a successful request for `http://url/of/svg.svg`. The image is displayed correctly.

But in Safari I just get the 404 for `{scope}`, it never attempts to request the SVG. No image is displayed.

Is there something special I have to do to get Safari to respect scope changes for SVGs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing "data" to "ng-attr-data" which meant the first URL the browser tried to load was the correct URL.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" ng-attr-data="{{svg}}" />
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KRicytAH1PtoVddrDEn5?p=preview